# Clarification on my answer about equations of lines

Tags: geometry

I was doing some work when i stumbled upon a question which i quickly solved, until i found out that i actually didn't.
The Question was:

> Find the equation of the line parallel to 2x − 3y + 1 = 0 and passing through (2,2)

I arrived to the conclusion of y = $\frac{-2x}{3}$+$\frac{2}{3}$

I first turned the equation  2x − 3y + 1 = 0 into slope intercept form y-y$^1$ =m(x-x$^1$)
then substituted back into y=mx+b

But when i checked the answers the answer was 2x+3y+2=0?
Was there something that i missed?, perhaps i needed to exapand? or am i just plain wrong?.

Comment: Have you copied the equation from the answer key correctly? The point $(2,2)$ doesn’t even satisfy that equation. The coefficient of $y$ should be $-3$, not $3$. I suggest double-checking your work for sign errors. If you can’t find any, then edit this question to include the details of your solution, and I’m sure that someone will be able to point out your error.

Comment: @amd i double checked and its indeed correct, I'm gonna have to follow up with my teachers once our school starts.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is also incorrect: $(2,2)$ doesn’t satisfy your equation, either. As I wrote above, double-check your work for sign errors.

Comment: @amd the equation that i calculated or the equation from the answer?

Comment: Both are incorrect. You should get into the habit of checking your work, in this case by verifying that the line actually passes through the point that it’s supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i figured it out, heres how the working out goes:

2x-3y+1=0

2x+1=3y

$\frac{2x}{3}$+$\frac{1}{3}$ = y

$\frac{2}{3}$ is also our gradient

use formula m = $\frac{y-y1}{x-x1}$

$\frac{2}{3}$ = $\frac{y-2}{x-2}$

2(x-2) = 3(y-2)

2x-4 = 3y -6

2x-3y+2=0

Thank you to everyone who helped me with this

Answer (score 0):

Two parallel lines have the same linear coefficients, to a common factor. Hence any parallel to

$$2x-3y+1=0$$

can be written as

$$2x-3y+p=0$$ (to a common factor). $p$ can be found by plugging the coordinates of the point.

Unless there is a typo, the given answer cannot be right.

Comment: what is ? im not familiar with it

Comment: @Xardous: an arbitrary common factor.

Comment: @Xardous: I have simplified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer and the  given answer are both wrong. The correct answer is $y=\frac 2  3(x+1)$ or $2x-3y+2=0$.

[The slope of the line is $\frac  2 3$, not $-\frac  2 3$].